# Not returning public ip in npm

Tags: node.js, npm

On my local server it was correctly giving me my public ip in result but when i uploaded it on live than instead of my public ip it gets me ip of my server. How to get correct ip. My code is simple as below

```
var PublicIp=require('public-ip');
sole.log(ip);
       PublicIp.v4().then(ip => {
con });
```

Also tried other packages like ipfy , external-ip but all returning same. So how can i get public ip , which other package can be used ?

Comment: Would like to hear about your cloud/server setup. Are you using any load balancer in-between or your server has the public-IP address?

Comment: Yes using load balancer.

Comment: Whenever you make the request to find the public-IP, the request is not routed through LB, that's why you get an IP of your server and not the LB.

Comment: I see , so any solution to this ?

Comment: How do you access your LB? through hostname?

Comment: Sorry , but server on which i was trying was testing server and it does not have any load balancer.